# cast.player.api.Host.licenseCustomData usage

Tags: chromecast, google-cast, drm

I've been trying to play a video which uses Smooth Streaming + PlayReady and requires custom license data. I've checked it's playable in Android and with a Silverlight player. For CHromecast, I need to use a CORS Proxy so the URL is slightly different (it includes the CORS proxy URL).

In order to play that video on Chromecast, I'm basing my code on the sample provided at https://github.com/googlecast/CastMediaPlayerStreamingDRM adding some lines to call host.licenseCustomData.

1) Lines added to payload parsing

```
... 
} else if(payload['type']==='licenseCredentials') {
    licenseCredentials = payload['value'];
    setDebugMessage('licenseCredentials', licenseCredentials);
} else if(payload['type']==='customData') {
    customData = payload['value'];
    setDebugMessage('customData', customData);

} else {
    licenseUrl = null;
}
...
```

2) Lines added to updateLicenseRequestInfo section

```
...
if( licenseCredentials ) { 
    mediaHost.updateLicenseRequestInfo = function(requestInfo) {
      // example of setting CORS withCredentials
      requestInfo.withCredentials = true;
    };
  }

if (customData) {
  mediaHost.updateLicenseRequestInfo = function(requestInfo) {
  mediaHost.licenseCustomData=customData;
  console.log("### customData: "+customData);
  };
}

if( licenseUrl ) {
...
```

The Console log shows that customData has the value I've set from the sender application.

But when I connect the debug tool to my chromecast and launch the App and send the video url to the receiver along with the custom data, the request made from the chromecast to the license server lacks the field CUSTOMDATA in the soap envelope, which is included when I play the video in Silverlight. That makes the receiver complain with "### HOST ERROR - Fatal Error: code = 2 mpl.js:639
Error fetching the keys or decrypting the content. "

What am I doing wrong when invoking that method? Is that method intended to be used when sending customData to the license server?

This is the soap request from the chromecast:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
    <AcquireLicense xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/DRM/2007/03/protocols">
    <challenge>
        <Challenge xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/DRM/2007/03/protocols/messages">
        <LA xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/DRM/2007/03/protocols" Id="SignedData" xml:space="preserve">
        <Version>1</Version>
        <ContentHeader>
            <WRMHEADER xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/DRM/2007/03/PlayReadyHeader" version="4.0.0.0">
            <DATA>
                <PROTECTINFO>
                    <KEYLEN>16</KEYLEN>
                    <ALGID>AESCTR</ALGID>
                </PROTECTINFO>
                <KID>Et0Diz60AUO2SbPZI2rnBw==</KID>
                <CHECKSUM>0NBYomW+Vu0=</CHECKSUM>
                <LA_URL>http://sldrm.licensekeyserver.com/core/rightsmanager.asmx</LA_URL>
                <LUI_URL>http://sldrm.licensekeyserver.com/core/rightsmanager.asmx?cid=xB9voVd%2fSkKDv1DGXA4RqQ%3d%3d</LUI_URL>
                <CUSTOMATTRIBUTES xmlns="">
                    <CID>a16f1fc4-7f57-424a-83bf-50c65c0e11a9</CID>
                    <DRMTYPE>smooth</DRMTYPE>
                </CUSTOMATTRIBUTES>
            </DATA>
        </WRMHEADER>
    </ContentHeader>
    <ClientInfo>
        <ClientVersion>1.2.0.1404</ClientVersion>
    </ClientInfo>
    <RevocationLists>
        <RevListInfo>
            <ListID>ioydTlK2p0WXkWklprR5Hw==</ListID>
            <Version>10</Version>
        </RevListInfo>
        <RevListInfo>
            <ListID>BOZ1zT1UnEqfCf5tJOi/kA==</ListID>
            <Version>11</Version>
        </RevListInfo>
        <RevListInfo>
            <ListID>Ef/RUojT3U6Ct2jqTCChbA==</ListID>
            <Version>13</Version>
        </RevListInfo>
    </RevocationLists>
    <LicenseNonce>Csbg/bANEEN+F/6qONjM1A==</LicenseNonce>
    <EncryptedData xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element">
    <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc"/>
    <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <EncryptedKey xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
    <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/DRM/2007/03/protocols#ecc256"/>
    <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <KeyName>WMRMServer</KeyName>
</KeyInfo>
<CipherData>
    <CipherValue>TrI33EPlN0od88NhZgBAhWMG85DUb1PV4x7pBZDmwl0/vFIvl1CckuxAoRtVwNNVFlfiNiX6K1Q1nhX7DGXqOdA664CIK7/OwdlpBYb+9QXZMdgholjJMhLkxtjwLWQRW1wwA1w2H+1QqEJXcFUt/VbbO1d4iAUsvkDz2pBGyOQ=</CipherValue>
</CipherData>
</EncryptedKey>
</KeyInfo>
<CipherData>
    <CipherValue>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</CipherValue>
</CipherData>
</EncryptedData>
</LA>
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<SignedInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/DRM/2007/03/protocols#ecdsa-sha256"/>
<Reference URI="#SignedData">
    <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/DRM/2007/03/protocols#sha256"/>
    <DigestValue>XeX+gAycOTO5tO3lupyPCaZo4+mHqThZiwf9FoU0EAU=</DigestValue>
</Reference>
</SignedInfo>
<SignatureValue>r8cshogs8x+4dxxTRuHeQ+pMgF8VnbSPXaEHf2la7dlnAPul6iKkWCbkiy7+OhNnR0aTDn+tJt+yJbgDeMyjdg==</SignatureValue>
<KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<KeyValue>
    <ECCKeyValue>
        <PublicKey>DNn77CHx0hdPgZvTNJgtS1Wc/6tVwas11asu+a6DEWSPEbLhDht7SbT67yqIpW11GclPbml/JhSblJsFURpd+Q==</PublicKey>
    </ECCKeyValue>
</KeyValue>
</KeyInfo>
</Signature>
</Challenge>
</challenge>
</AcquireLicense>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And this is the one from Silverlight:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
    <AcquireLicense xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/DRM/2007/03/protocols">
    <challenge>
        <Challenge xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/DRM/2007/03/protocols/messages">
        <LA xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/DRM/2007/03/protocols" Id="SignedData" xml:space="preserve">
        <Version>1</Version>
        <ContentHeader>
            <WRMHEADER xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/DRM/2007/03/PlayReadyHeader" version="4.0.0.0">
            <DATA>
                <PROTECTINFO>
                    <KEYLEN>16</KEYLEN>
                    <ALGID>AESCTR</ALGID>
                </PROTECTINFO>
                <KID>Et0Diz60AUO2SbPZI2rnBw==</KID>
                <CHECKSUM>0NBYomW+Vu0=</CHECKSUM>
                <LA_URL>http://sldrm.licensekeyserver.com/core/rightsmanager.asmx</LA_URL>
                <LUI_URL>http://sldrm.licensekeyserver.com/core/rightsmanager.asmx?cid=xB9voVd%2fSkKDv1DGXA4RqQ%3d%3d</LUI_URL>
                <CUSTOMATTRIBUTES xmlns="">
                    <CID>a16f1fc4-7f57-424a-83bf-50c65c0e11a9</CID>
                    <DRMTYPE>smooth</DRMTYPE>
                </CUSTOMATTRIBUTES>
            </DATA>
        </WRMHEADER>
    </ContentHeader>
    <CLIENTINFO>
        <CLIENTVERSION>2.0.0.1446</CLIENTVERSION>
    </CLIENTINFO>
    <RevocationLists>
        <RevListInfo>
            <ListID>ioydTlK2p0WXkWklprR5Hw==</ListID>
            <Version>10</Version>
        </RevListInfo>
        <RevListInfo>
            <ListID>gC4IKKPHsUCCVhnlttibJw==</ListID>
            <Version>11</Version>
        </RevListInfo>
        <RevListInfo>
            <ListID>BOZ1zT1UnEqfCf5tJOi/kA==</ListID>
            <Version>12</Version>
        </RevListInfo>
        <RevListInfo>
            <ListID>Ef/RUojT3U6Ct2jqTCChbA==</ListID>
            <Version>22</Version>
        </RevListInfo>
    </RevocationLists>
    <CustomData>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</CustomData>
    <LicenseNonce>SQDD6dIQNXVXLNKOCet2xQ==</LicenseNonce>
    <EncryptedData xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element">
    <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc"/>
    <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <EncryptedKey xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
    <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/DRM/2007/03/protocols#ecc256"/>
    <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <KeyName>WMRMServer</KeyName>
</KeyInfo>
<CipherData>
    <CipherValue>8Kfzf28bYpkwzIBB1wZSQX+ZT7KS9EZL25Xs4pAto8ujqOufHz452VL/iJ5TRmWpf1+gjh0Wry3cg6lyiiZJnYMrDKQKwQJxiPoTk58Zc4FIGhrAJl5L3OobpYhOywJzRryB8TxkiNXeHW34E2PuduU50etksWHuPxJjSMlgbvE=</CipherValue>
</CipherData>
</EncryptedKey>
</KeyInfo>
<CipherData>
    <CipherValue>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</CipherValue>
</CipherData>
</EncryptedData>
</LA>
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<SignedInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/DRM/2007/03/protocols#ecdsa-sha256"/>
<Reference URI="#SignedData">
    <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/DRM/2007/03/protocols#sha256"/>
    <DigestValue>YxEZEHdaee41melLgCquubdVrJwQu/elIajlsLl+FmQ=</DigestValue>
</Reference>
</SignedInfo>
<SignatureValue>ooeQ9d4aPstpNo8j/zGo3Z0O0IQk9YHe7Pwh+UDTsqbVF4/BrKR2n5mV1T8ykp+2EAYQWmpc58kXuRKcrrcjWw==</SignatureValue>
<KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<KeyValue>
    <ECCKeyValue>
        <PublicKey>DnKjqSgywqA8mynNPAo1qzh0hE2ndzG5Fe39gGvlGIEEY7uamNYQAY9u0DTnevLgPmsGSDzrV8cZohBFr2exVw==</PublicKey>
    </ECCKeyValue>
</KeyValue>
</KeyInfo>
</Signature>
</Challenge>
</challenge>
</AcquireLicense>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: What version of the Media Player Library are you using on your receiver side?

Comment: 0.9.0, the latest available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all make sure that Media Player Library 0.9.0 is being used

//www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/libs/mediaplayer/0.9.0/media_player.js

That's the officially supported version now.

Secondly I've updated the code at

https://github.com/googlecast/CastMediaPlayerStreamingDRM

to include license custom data. Now you can set license custom data from sender side and see it on receiver side using remote debugging.

Note that mediaHost.licenseCustomData needs to be set

```
  if (customData) {
    mediaHost.licenseCustomData=customData;
    console.log("### customData: "+customData);
  }
```

before mediaHost.updateLicenseRequestInfo is called because MPL needs access to licenseCustomData when it receives needkey event and then calls generateKeyRequest.

Comment: Great! Let me paste here the sample video I was testing just in case somebody else wants to do a similar test: http://www.corsproxy.com/djkxw9frc3oss.cloudfront.net/ss/buydrmdemo/bbb_h264_1080p_3mbps_drm/big_buck_bunny_1080p_h264.ism/Manifest